# Warnings when including C header file with C++ compiler

Tags: c++, c, gcc, include

I have some header file that was written for use in a C99 program. This header includes all the function definitions, and is not paired with a source file. I am including it in a C++ file.

My C++ compiler flags include `-pedantic -std=c++11`, which gives me various warnings in the header file such as "ISO C++ forbids compound literals", and "ISO C++ forbids variable length arrays". Obviously the C++ compiler is treating the C99 code as C++. Two questions:

1. Is this a potential problem when trying to write code that will run correctly on various platforms using different compilers?
2. What is a good way to resolve the warnings, and produce standard conforming code? I was thinking of making a precompiled header file using gcc, but don't know enough about the process to be assured that I am not going to have unintended consequences from included a C precompiled header in a C++ source.

Thanks

Comment: Try gnu++XX (XX = 98, 03, or 11); otherwise, you'll have to come up w/ a cleaner solution.

Comment: @dans3itz: I am using -std=c++11. Is that what you mean?

Comment: 1 => yes. 2 => create a C89 interface to the C99 code, and place the C++ include in an `extern "C"` block. by the way C99 is itself a portability concern. visual c++ in Windows does not support C99.

Comment: Well, C++ does not support a lot of C99 features. So there won't be any real way to make this portable. gnu++11 will provide an extension language to C++11 making the code 'work.' This might get you past this stage, but ultimately, you're going to need to sep. C++ and C99 modules and just make calls out the C interface. C99's portability alone is a concern, honestly.

Comment: portability on windows is the concern, not C99. This is what standards are made for.

Comment: You *may* be able to work around at least some of this problem by referring to the directory containing the problem file with `-isystem` rather than `-I`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To include a pure C header file(*) in a C++ project, you should wrap the include statement in an `extern "C"` block:

```
// C++
extern "C" {
// C-code goes here
#include "foo.h"
}
```

This is because C++ performs name mangling on all function names to make overloading work. C doesn't use name mangling, so C++ parses C function signatures *with* name mangling.

Please note that `extern "C"` doesn't put the compiler into "C-mode" (there is no such mode but you might falsely think of this instruction as such), **it doesn't mangle the function names** (+ changes the calling convention and forbids overloading; thanks for *doomster* for pointing these things out).

However, it shouldn't be a problem if you are including a *header only* (with inline implementations), since this name mangling will only be a problem when you *link* the C source file or library against your C++ project, since the function names are different in this case.

This being said, you should use the **common subset** of C and C++ for the **header file**, extract and compile the implementations of these functions separately with a C compiler, not C++. Then, you (hopefully) can link both parts together. A lot of C libraries already have headers which are compatible with C++, so this is a common procedure.

(*): Some header files are already made to be compatible with both languages C and C++ by using the common subset of language features plus wrapping everything in a *conditional* `extern "C"` block. For such headers, you should not use this method, but only for the ones which don't have such a block in it.

Comment: Just to stress this point, the C++ compiler will never compile anything as C code, not even when in an `extern "C"` clause!

Comment: @doomster You're right, it just doesn't mangle the names. I want to emphasize this in my answer, thanks for this hint.

Comment: There are other aspects to this, for example it could change the function calling convention (the way that parameters are passed to/from functions). Also, you can't overload extern "C" functions, not even by putting them into different namespaces (apart from anonymous namespaces, I believe).

Comment: @doomster Thanks again; I edited my answer. I hope it is correct some day ;)

Answer (score 5):

> Is this a potential problem when trying to write code that will run correctly on various platforms using different compilers?

Yes. GCC may just give a warning, other compilers (e.g. Visual Studio, or GCC with other options) could very well give an error.

> What is a good way to resolve the warnings, and produce standard conforming code?

The correct way to resolve the problems is to write the header in the common subset of C and C++. Functions and object-definitions that use C99 features (such as variable-length arrays and compound literals) should be moved to a separate C source file (that gets compiled with a C compiler!).